# How to show my website language based on browser language detect

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I hope you all are doing fine. I build a website using wordpress cms and I'm using Polylang plugin. Now I want that the website to be displayed based on the browser detected language. So if the browser's language is german, the website should be displayed in german and if the browser language is other from german language it should be displayed in english language. Polylang has an option to use browser detection but when I do this, the website is displayed only in the browser language and it doesn't allows me to switch to the english version when I click english flag. Can someone help?

[image]